# How to select some keys in a dictionary in jinja2 when iterating over them

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a dictionary like this

```
[ { 'a' : "Aa1",
    'b' : "Bb1",
    'c' : "Cc1"
  } ,

  { 'a' : "Aa2",
    'b' : "Bb2",
    'c' : "Cc2"
    'd' :"Dd2"
 } ]
```

I want to reject some keys while looping through this array of dictionaries. So I want result something like

**reject key "a" and "b"**

```
c = Cc1

c = Cc2
d = Dd2
```

How can I accomplish that

I have tried something like this

```
{ % for dict in dictionaries % }
     {%- for key,value in dict.items()%}
        {%- if key|rejectattr("a", "b") %}
          {{key}} = {{value }}
        {%- endif%}    
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor % }
```

However this does not work. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

What you're actually saying with your `rejectattr` filter is "the value of `key.a` cannot be `'b'`", which isn't what you're trying to do. Since you're working directly with the key, it's just a `str`, and doesn't have any such attribute.

Maybe try using `equalto` as the test, and `reject` as the main filter:

```
{% if key|reject('equalto', 'a')|reject('equalto', 'b') %}
```

Comment: Just `{% if key not in ['a', 'b'] %}`